# How to generate PDF from an active View Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a search box when user input roll no, it returns the specific student result. I want to generate PDF of that searched data, that data is in table.
[image]
**Main Question : I want to generate PDF for the result of student who has searched for his/her data, so how to generate PDF for that current student result.**

**Print/PDF Generator Button:**

```
 <a href="{!! url('/getPDF') !!}">Print</a>
```

**PDFController:**

```
class PDFController extends Controller
{
    public function getPDF(Request $request){
            // I want some code here to get the current student result so that I can generate pdf for the current student
            $pdf = PDF::loadView('results.single');
            return $pdf->stream('result.pdf');
    }
}
```

**SearchController:**

```
class ResultsSearchController extends Controller
{
    public function search()
    {
        $keyword = Input::get('keyword');
        $row = Student::where('rollno',$keyword)->first();
        $rollno = $row['rollno'];
        if($keyword == $rollno){
            return View::make('results.single')
            ->with('search',Student::where('rollno',$keyword)
            ->get())->with('keyword',$keyword);
        }else{
            return view('errors.404');
        }
    }
}
```

**Routes.php:**

```
Route::get('/getPDF', 'PDFController@getPDF');
```

PS : I am using https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Comment: From the Laravel dompdf documentation they mention where you can use loadView method to do so

Comment: When you run the search, are you doing it using a query string? Or are you doing this through a POST request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

First of all change route to

```
Route::get('/getPDF/{id}', 'yourController@getPDF');
```

Pass the Searched Student `id` from single view to PDF view like this

```
<a href="{!! url('/getPDF', $student->id) !!}"> Print</a>
```

and in your **PDF Controller**

```
public function getPDF(Request $request,$id){
    $student = Student::findOrFail($id);
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.result',['student' => $student]);
    return $pdf->stream('result.pdf', array('Attachment'=>0));              
}
```

and get the **object** in your view like

```
{!! $student->property !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `PDF::loadView()` I think you need to include the search results, just as you do in `search()`

```
$keyword = Input::get('keyword');
$row = Student::where('rollno',$keyword)->first();
$rollno = $row['rollno'];
if($keyword == $rollno){
    $results = Student::where('rollno',$keyword)->get();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('results.single', [
                'search' => $results, 
                'keyword' => $keyword
                ]);
    return $pdf->stream('result.pdf');
}
```