# Laravel: Generate PDF of Blade View and Store it in specified folder

Tags: php, html, laravel, file, pdf

I have a Laravel Blade View, which is fetching data from Database. It is working perfectly.
Here is my Controller:

```
$model = new outbound_detail;
    $data = $model->where('reference', $reference)->get();
    $sku_count = $data->count();
    $model2 = new outbounds;
    $data_model2 = $model2->where('reference',$reference)->first();
    $date = $data_model2->created_at;
    return view('ims.release.release_invoice',compact('data'))->with('sku_count',$sku_count)->with('reference',$reference)->with('date',$date)->with('warehouse',$warehouse);
```

Now instead of returning this view I want to save this view as PDF in my folder: public/uploads
I have already installed the composer for DOMPDF.
How can I convert this page to pdf with passing all variables to view file without returning the view.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415939/how-to-generate-pdf-from-an-active-view-laravel) and [this](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf#using)

Comment: Take a look at https://pineco.de/simple-pdf-rendering-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

i use this libraries, it's depends on your needs:

> https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf
> https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
> https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf
> https://packagist.org/packages/carlos-meneses/laravel-mpdf